# Angular 2+, async testing and setTimeout

Tags: angular, unit-testing, asynchronous, testing

I have a question about testing.
I use Angular 6, karma and jasmine.

My test is:

```
it(`my test`, async(() => {
    console.log('### start test');
    fixture.detectChanges();
    // call a method which has async code
    fixture.componentInstance.fakeTimeout();
    console.log('isStable', fixture.isStable());
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
        // here I must check smth only when all async operations are completed
        console.log('### end test');
    });
}));
```

I've tried to implement the `fakeTimeout` method in different ways, namely:

```
public fakeTimeout() {
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('>>>>>> COMPONENT TIMEOUT!!!');
            resolve(true);
        }, 2000);
    }).then(() => {});
}
```

or

```
public fakeTimeout() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('>>>>>> COMPONENT TIMEOUT!!!');
    }, 2000);
}
```

In both cases I had a following log:

```
### start test
isStable true
### end test
>>>>>> COMPONENT TIMEOUT!!!
```

But, according to the official documentation, `whenStable` promise resolves only then all async operations are completed, and a log must be:

```
### start test
isStable true
>>>>>> COMPONENT TIMEOUT!!!
### end test
```

What did I do wrong? How should I write an async test correctly, provided that I must wait for a completion of all async operations into my component?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, why `fixture.whenStable()` does not wait for the `delay (setTimeout)` by itself.

But it works fine with normal `Promise` or `Observable` return

But you can solve it either ways :

**Method 1** : You can wait manually using `tick()` utilizing `fakeAync`

```
it(`my test`, fakeAsync(() => {
    console.log('### start test');
    fixture.detectChanges();
    // call a method which has async code
    fixture.componentInstance.fakeTimeout();
    tick(2100); // just more than the delay mentioned inside the component.
    console.log('isStable', fixture.isStable());
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
        // here I must check smth only when all async operations are completed
        console.log('### end test');
    });
}));
```

**Method 2** : Have your own `setTimeout` inside the spec file and complete the test using `done()`

```
it(`my test`, ((done) => {
        console.log('### start test');
        fixture.detectChanges();
        // call a method which has async code
        fixture.componentInstance.fakeTimeout();
        setTimeout(()=> {
          console.log('isStable', fixture.isStable());
          console.log('### end test');
          done();
        },2100)
}));
```